# Replace null value with NA using Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration, pentaho-spoon

I have an input csv file with one column field value as empty. I want to replace that field value as NA in my destination table. And in my destination table that column is specified as not null column.

I tried using if field value is null, value mapper step. but it doesnt work out.. can anyone suggest how to proceed.

Comment: you can use replace string step, you can't use field value is null step.

Comment: the if field value step should work fine here: did you check the box "select fields"? than you can choose the fields to be transformed to NA if null...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NULLS can not be replaced using `If field value is null` step if you enable Lazy Conversion in `CSV input` step.

So untick the `lazy conversion?` check box in `CSV Input` step. Then in `If field value is null` step check `Select fields` check box and select the field you want to check nulls and type NA in Replace by value column.

Answer (score 0):

there is a specific step that does just that-
it replaces null values - In the Step you have a choice to a) pick either 1 or more field type(s) (STRING, INTEGER, etc.) or b) identify specific field(s) - then you provide a replacement string if you wish.